# May I ask a difference between a database specific term and a technology generic term?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a persistent doubt about the difference of data warehousing and data archiving, but I fear being downvoted to hell by posting this in DBA. Is it ok, or is it off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

2 seconds on Google and you'd be able to answer the question yourself:

- ["Data archiving is the process of moving data that is no longer actively used to a separate data storage device for long-term retention"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22data+archiving%22)
- ["In computing, a data warehouse (DW or DWH), also known as an enterprise data warehouse (EDW), is a system used for reporting and data analysis"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22data+warehousing%22).

Note that "no longer actively used" and "used for reporting and data analysis" are very different things.

That's not all there is to it, but hover over the downvote button on main and it says "This question does not show any research effort...", and so yes, I think you'd gather a few for the question you are proposing.